# IE 7 & 8 jqplot misalignment while printing

Tags: javascript, css, jqplot

I am having some trouble getting the graph created with jqplot to print with proper alignment in IE 7 & 8. It looks great on the screen, but once I click print preview it get's all messed up.

Help me please

Alignment in IE 9, Firefox and Chrome is perfect. Any help would be greatly appreciated

[image: https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/_eXAGzNHBomg/TbgxHZiwFRI/AAAAAAAACwg/CQqXHN2CkZA/s800/d01.png]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added a class iterator to the canvases and then use browser hacks to perfectly alignment the bars for different browsers.

This is the modified excanvas : http://pastebin.com/mgHUbe3S

Line 309 is where the magic happens

```
    var el = surfaceElement.ownerDocument.createElement('div');
    **el.className = "seriesContainer_"+counter;**
    el.style.width =  surfaceElement.clientWidth + 'px';
    el.style.height = surfaceElement.clientHeight + 'px';
    el.style.overflow = 'hidden';
    el.style.position = 'absolute';
    surfaceElement.appendChild(el);

    this.element_ = el;
    this.arcScaleX_ = 1;
    this.arcScaleY_ = 1;
    this.lineScale_ = 1;
    counter++;
  }
```

Comment: you sure your accessing the series container class correctly ?

Comment: what I did is I copy your  js file and replaced mine, I thought that was the solution?

Comment: ferronrsmith What sort of customization are we talking about here is just replacing the `excanvas.js` doesn't work. Could you please elaborate on that? For now I must say that the solution given by @user1065335 (+1) is my preferred one as it is simply copy & paste and it works great :)

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://blog.muonlab.com/2010/06/02/getting-position-absolute-canvas-elements-to-print-correctly-in-ie/) worked for me. It's a javascript function that resets the absolute position of each canvas.

Comment: +1 this is a very nice find. I used the information from the link and I built a code sample, [posted in my answer to a similar problem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11470132/613495), to see the results of this solution. It works just great.

Comment: the link privided  is dead!

Answer (score -1):

Go through your printing settings and make sure it is CSS enabled.